# removing leading zeros from IP addresses: converting ipfilter.dat to bluetack.co.uk ipfilter with sed

Tags: performance, bash, sed, awk

I had a need to convert uTorrent-style ipfilter.dat into a bluetack-style ipfilter file, and wrote this shell script to achieve this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# read ipfilter.dat-formatted file line by line
# (example: 000.000.000.000-008.008.003.255,000,Badnet
# - ***here, input file's lines/fields are always the same length***)
# and convert into a bluetack.co.uk-formatted output
# (example: Badnet:0.0.0.0-8.8.3.255
# - fields moved around, leading zeros removed)

while read record
do
start=`echo ${record:0:15} | awk -F '.' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=$i+0;}1' OFS='.'`
end=`echo ${record:16:15} | awk -F '.' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=$i+0;}1' OFS='.'`
echo ${record:36:7}:${start}-${end}
done < $1
```

However, on a 2000-line input file this script takes on average 10(!) seconds to complete - a mere 200 lines/sec.

I'm sure this same result can be achieved with sed, and sed-version is likely to be much faster.

Is there a sed-guru around to suggest a solution for this kind of fixed-positions replacements?

Feel free to suggest a solution in other languages as well - I would enjoy testing a Python or a C version, for example. A more efficient shell/bash version would be welcome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this.

```
sed -r 's/^0*([0-9]+)\.0*([0-9]+)\.0*([0-9]+)\.0*([0-9]+)-0*([0-9]+)\.0*([0-9]+)\.0*([0-9]+)\.0*([0-9]+),...,(.*)$/\9:\1.\2.\3.\4-\5.\6.\7.\8/' inputfile
```

I didn't test the performance but I guess it could be faster than 200 lines/sec.

Comment: Hmm, after comprehending your sed line - it is really easier than I thought, could have achieved the same with a manageable effort. Thanks - next time I'll know how to solve a similar problem with sed.

Answer (score 1):

You will be sacrificing performance using the shell's while read loop on a big file. It is empirically proven that tools such as `awk/sed` (and some languages eg Perl/Python/Ruby) are better at iterating big files and processing the lines than the shell's while read loop. Moreover, in your script, while iterating over the lines, you are also piping a few calls to `awk`. This is extra overheads.

Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ cat file
000.000.000.000-008.008.003.255,000,Badnet
001.010.110.111-002.020.220.222,111,Badnet

$ ruby -F"," -ane 'puts "#{$F[-1].chomp}:" + $F[0].gsub(/(00|0)([0-9]+)([.-])/,"\\2\\3")'   file
Badnet:0.0.0.0-8.8.3.255
Badnet:1.10.110.111-2.20.220.222
```

Comment: (Is it only on fool's day that unicorns give me a thumbs-up on an upvote?) I agree with what you had to say about shell (and my script), though most of the time it is shell which is used for this kind of easy data manipulation. Regarding your Ruby example: it is on average faster than sed - ~0.040s. Thanks for this one!

Answer (score 0):

I really wanted to get this to work in a single sed command, but I wasn't able to figure it out. Surely this will still be faster than 200 lines/s though.

`sed 's/\.0\{1,2\}/\./g' | sed 's/^0\{1,2\}//'`

Answer (score 0):

`#!/bin/tclsh`

```
#Regsub TCL script to remove the leading zeros from the ip address.

#Author : Shoeb Masood , Bangalore

puts "Enter the ip address"
set ip [gets stdin]
set list_ip [split $ip .]
foreach index $list_ip {
regsub  {^0|^00} $index {\1} index
lappend list_ip2 $index
}
set list_ip2 [join $list_ip2 "."]
puts $list_ip2
```